# How to run groups of commands in parallel?

Tags: linux, process-management, parallelism

I am trying to run groups of commands in parallel. There are 10 groups and each group has 3 commands. I want sequential execution within each group and parallel execution of the 10 groups. I am trying something like this, but this does not seem to work:

```
(command11; command12; command13 &)
(command21; command22; command23 &)
(command31; command32; command33 &)
(command41; command42; command43 &)
...
```

Answer (score 6):

#### As you wish

Nearly hit. The correct syntax is:

```
(command11; command12; command13) &
(command21; command22; command23) &
(command31; command32; command33) &
(command41; command42; command43) &
```

#### As you wish, but better

Or, if you want *inside a group* the commands to be left out after a command failed, then the syntax is

```
command11 && command12 && command13 &
command21 && command22 && command23 &
command31 && command32 && command33 &
command41 && command42 && command43 &
```

Note, "`&&`" has a very different meaning as "`&`". "`&&`" means, that the command will run only after the previous is ready, and only if it was executed without a failure (i.e. its exit code is zero). "`&`" means that the command before it will be run parallel with the main execution line, and its failure or success doesn't matter.

#### Using the `xargs` tool

However, these solutions have the disadvantage, that you *can't wait* after *all* of these commands were executed. To do that, we have a little bit more trickery. Specially in your case, the required command to do this would be

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
  echo "command${i}1 && command${i}2 && command${i}3"
done | xargs -P 10 -l 1 bash -c
```

It uses the very useful `xargs` tool. Of course you can pipe anything into it, for example if you want to process thousands of things in 10 threads parallel, it will do.

It works on a way, that it calls the command `bash -c` for all lines of input, *parallel*, but so, that always at most 10 child processes will coincidentally run (this is done by the `-P 10`). The `xargs` command end only if all of the bash processes were executed.

#### Parallel tool (see other answers)

The GNU has also written a tool named `parallel` as well. As far I know, its syntax is a little bit more clear as of the `xargs`s, although it has lesser features and it is not so common. Likely other answers will explain it.

#### NodeJs "parallel" module

If you are working in the *nodejs* framework, also there is a very commonly used tool (`npm install parallel`), which is used mainly for parallelizing automatized build tasks, but it can be used also in shellscripts easily.

It is not a very good idea in common environments, because `npm` packages don't integrate very well with the Unix packet-handling environment. Although its syntax are far more easy, its features are far behind all of the other solutions.

---

In the case of your specific problem, I would likely choose the second solution in a simple case, and the xargs-based solution in a more complex one.

Comment: Checking the parallel, I think it nearly so many as `xargs`, although also its syntax is nearly so complex, if you use for complex tasks. For easy tasks, it is much simpler.

Comment: GNU Parallel is built to be switch compatible with `xargs`.

Comment: based on this answer we used `while read remote_file; do echo "$remote_file $target_folder"; done < files.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 10 hdfs dfs -get` which worked great at downloading hundreds of files in half the time.

Comment: @simbo1905 Thank you very much! It is very nice to hear.

Answer (score 5):

With **GNU Parallel** it would be:

```
parallel 'command{}1; command{}2; command{}3' ::: {1..4}
```

or if you prefer **Command substitution**:

```
parallel 'command{}1; command{}2; command{}3' ::: $(seq 4)
```

GNU Parallel has about 150 job control option which you might want to study but start with the [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/OpaiGYxkSuQ?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1).